# Purpose of Android DDMS console view : should I expect it to show stack traces?

Tags: android

I understand that DDMS allows debuggers to connect to emulators/android devices. But what exactly is the purpose of DDMS console view shown in eclipse ?

It shows the status of adb connection failures,

but should I expect stack trace of crashing programs ? I only see stack trace/crashes in logcat but not in ddms console.

Any ideas ?

Thanks,

Comment: Yes I am using eclipse with ADT

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't show up much, but usually it will pop open when adb is acting up. I think, like the Android one, it shows what stdout would say (text that the commandline version would dump). I have never seen a stack trace in that console view.

There's a few times where I have problems like adb acting up, and I have to run commands on the command-line like "adb kill-server" and DDMS would freak out and try to reconnect, usually 11 attempts.

Answer (score 0):

Console View is a part of eclipse and not of DDMS please refer [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/ddms.html) whereas console view has its own function refer [here](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/views/console/ref-console_view.htm) hope it will help when your app crashes generally you can identify error in logcat View it shows you detail runtime error if any... This answer is based on what I understood from your question if its not related pls comment below I'll delete.

Answer (score -1):

In the DDMS view you're able to directly connect to the emulator. For example, you're able to call the emulator, send sms to the emulator and also the geo location.
The console tab in the DDMS serves no purpose other than to show you the communication between USB and the device.
You should not expect to see the log information in the Console tab.